# is it possible to integrate bc calculator in an app (script interpreter) as a library?

Tags: libraries, development, bc

is it possible to integrate bc command line calculator in an app (script interpreter) as a library?

I am not asking if that can be done, I am asking if there is something ready already that wraps bc and make it work as a library.

In ubuntu 22.04 I can't find any packages like bc-dev libbc-dev libbc ...

Searching for this subject on google doesnt help either.

My goal is to integrate the command line calculator interpreter `bc` inside a GPL game script interpreter called Arx Libertatis (Arx Fatalis).
So, when the game starts and it reads and interprets it's .asl script, it will find a line like ex.:
`Calc @result "(~@val1~*33)/~@val2~"` (where ~@val1~ will expand to 0.25 and ~@val2~ will expand to 7.123)
That script line shall send "(0.25*33)/7.123" to bc and assign it's result at @result.
But for that, I need to access the bc main function directly and not call the compiled bc binary.
So I am loogin for a libbc-dev somewhere, but I just can't find it.
Will I have to wrap it in a lib myself?

btw, it must have high performance, and if there is an alternative to `bc` that provides a faster result, it is important because it is a game and the calculations must happen as fast as possible.
Also, I could use flags to the Calc script command to determine what calculator interpreter will be used so `Calc -b ...` would use `bc`, while `Calc -d ...` could use some other library (and therefore mod developers must prepare it in a syntax that is recognized by the other library).

Comment: What language are you using that you want libraries for?  Why are you unable to use the language to call the binary?  You could use the math functions of whatever language you are using.  It appears `bc` is written in C, you can read the source to determine how best to implement it in your program.

Comment: yes, I think that will be the only option. it is CPP. I will have to directly access the functions (or the main function) of `bc`. I think calling the binary is probably slower than directly accessing the functions, and performance is essential.